GNOME Shell Isn't Managing All Open Windows. How to I Fix That?
When I started using Ubuntu a few years ago, one of the first things I did was to configure my install to automatically start a set of applications.  Those positions were distributed among a set of 4 workspaces. Running gnome-session-properties to get the startup apps shows the following:

Clementine
Firefox
Proton Mail Bridge
Signal
Thunderbird Mail

On startup, all of these programs do start.  However, if I remember correctly, Thunderbird and Firefox were no longer restored to the positions in the previous sessions when I started using Ubuntu 20.04.  Such behavior persists into 22.04 (which is what I'm using now).
Lately, I've been using Ubuntu for a wider range of tasks simultaneously, and as a result, I have multiple Firefox windows open at the same time.  Restarts have become somewhat messy, as I have to manually rearrange all of the windows that popup after a restart.  I finally had time to do some investigating with wmcrtl and first confirmed that the window manager being used is GNOME Shell.  I then found that no Mozilla products are listed when the wmctrl -l command is run.  See the output below:
0x00a00006  3 desktop Clementine
0x00c00004  0 desktop Signal (5)
0x02400004  0 desktop autodesk fusion 360 tutorial - YouTube - Chromium
0x02400015  5 desktop SawStop Professional Digital - Chromium
0x02400016  0 desktop A stolen beach and the black market for sand : Planet Money : NPR - Chromium
0x01800004  0 desktop Bitwarden
0x03800010  0 desktop Yubico Authenticator
0x03400019  0 desktop Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
0x03e002cb  2 desktop darktable
0x03600019  0 desktop Windows 10 VB [Running] - Oracle VM VirtualBox
0x04000004  0 desktop Joplin

This is the case despite the fact that 1 Thunderbird instance is running on workspace 0, and 5 Firefox instances are running across 2 workspaces.  I suspect that Firefox no longer starts in the positions from the previous session, because the programs aren't shown or managed by GNOME Shell, anymore.  I checked the wmctrl manual on manpages.ubuntu.com, but I did not find any option that can find and then add windows that are not managed by wmctrl.  So, my question to askubuntu.com is two fold.

How do I find windows and their IDs that are not being managed by GNOME Shell?
How do I force windows that are not being managed by GNOME Shell to be managed by GNOME Shell with wmctrl?
How do I ensure that GNOME Shell will continue managing added windows after the session is restarted?

One thing to note:  I've tried using the Firefox release from both the Snap Store, and directly from Mozilla, and the results were the same.  So, I'm assuming this issue is agnostic to the source of the install package.
Thanks,
